# How to display clock count down whole the application on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, timer, clock, countdown

I make and display an clock count down with this code

```
LabelField time;
            long mille=0;
            Timer timer=null;TimerTask task=null;
            public Timerscreen() {
                mille=1000*60*1;
                time=new LabelField();
                add(time);
                timer=new Timer();

                task=new TimerTask() {

                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {

                            if(mille!=0){
                                SimpleDateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss") ;
                                System.out.println("================="+date.formatLocal(mille)+"====================="+Thread.activeCount());
                                time.setText(date.formatLocal(mille));
                                mille=mille-1000;
                            }else{
time.setText("00:00");
mille=1000*60*1;
                                timer.cancel();
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Dialog.inform("Time expaired");
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.schedule(task,0, 1000);
```

And when I push a new screen , I want to this clock still display and count down.
How can I do that ?

Comment: come on chat room Now you have the permission."Knowledge Sharing Center For Blackberry and Java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add a single ui `field` or `manager` into two `manager`s or `screen`s.. every ui `field` or `manager` must have at most one parent (`screen` or `manager`).

So if you need a `LabelField` which will hold and show time on different `screen`s, then you only need to implement some sort of listener which will listen for the time changes.. and for every changes you have to update the `screen` and the `LabelField` with the new value. You have already implemented a `TimerTask` which will provide you updated data.

[Edited - added later]

you can check the following codes, not tested but something like this will solve your problem...

```
class MyTimerUtil {
    TimerListener listener = null;

    public MyTimerUtil() {      
    }

    public void setTimerListener(TimerListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        final int interval = 1000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                // add your codes..

                // notify others
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.timeChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 0, interval);
    }
}


interface TimerListener {
    public void timeChanged();
}

class ScreeA extends MainScreen implements TimerListener {

    public void timeChanged() {
        // add Codes here on time changed event     
    }   
}
```

in the above snippet, you can implement `TimerListener` interface in any screen instance and can get update on every time changed event by the `MyTimerUtil` class. For that, you have to set an instance of `ScreeA` (which implements `TimerListener`) via `setTimerListener()` of the `MyTimerUtil` class.

Also need to start the timer by calling `startTimer()` method.

Comment: "need to implement some sort of listener which will listen for the time changes". How to do this ? Can you let me understand with example code ?

Comment: I have added a code snippet. You can check this on the answer.